# «Шахнаме» или «Шах-наме»?

Tags: ономастика, слитно-дефис

Как всё же правильно? В русскоязычных источниках чаще встречаю «Шахнаме», в украиноязычных – «Шах-наме». Но есть и исключения. Хотелось бы знать точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Шахнаме» ([Словарь имён собственных](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5&all=x)). В Нацкорпусе найдено 6 вхождений "Шахнаме" и ни одного "Шах-наме".